Basement wall has a hole that crumbles to the touch
I was working in the basement and touched a spot on the wall which instantly crumbled and left a hole that is about 1.5” deep. The wall is made of cement and the remainder of that wall did not have any soft spots aside from this hole.
There are signs of water leaking along this wall from some time ago. I moved in 4 years ago and corrected the issue (a disconnected downspout). Since then, there hasn’t been any signs of water getting in to the basement.
What caused this portion of the wall to become brittle and what can I do to repair it?


Guessing a hole drilled/made into the wall for maybe an anchor for a bolt and then just covered over.  If the inside sides of the hole is hard to a screwdriver/nail/similar, then no worries.

agree with crip, it looks very circular hole after you get past the blowout portions.

It looks a lot like there was once a larger hole there that may have been filled in with poorly prepared mortar:

If the mortar was mixed too dry or if it had been wetted so much that the cement had washed away leaving mostly sand this could account for the crumbly nature of what you found.
